# Is an Oracle SID UPPERCASE or lowercase?

Tags: oracle

This may sound silly, but is an Oracle Service Identifier (SID) aka database name normally in upper or lowercase?

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/rilin/selecting-a-database-name.html#GUID-3C954866-8375-4319-9184-CAA5F3B299D4), a SID "can contain only the characters a-z, A-Z, and 0-9", so both upper and lowercase is allowed. In my experience, it usually doesn't really matter. However, I am installing Oracle 11.2 on a file system that is case sensitive, and a lot of directories and files have the SID in them (e.g. `initMYDB.ora`).

EDIT:

I found a [quote](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-create-the-oracle-password-file-using-orapwd-command/) saying that the SID in the password file name (`orapwMYDB`) is case sensitive and must match the instance name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case sensitive on Linux/UNIX and not case sensitive on Windows.

Comment: I see, thanks. Is there a convention people stick to, like always uppercase or always lowercase?

Comment: @wolφi Depends on the people or organization. I have seen both, even mixed. I prefer using uppercase. Oracle does that by default (I mean, when you download a pre-built VM or create a DB in their cloud). DBCA automatically creates a directory for the wallet with uppercase name when registering a database in a directory service, unless specified otherwise. ASM paths are converted to uppercase unless specified otherwise. ASM, APX and MGMTDB (built-in instances when using RAC) use uppercase ORACLE_SID. But these are just minor things.